# Choicechip data pass to another widget

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm learning flutter but there are some things that I cannot find anywhere.

For example, I want to pass choice chip data to listtile

[ChoiceChip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO2y5.png)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QmeeZeAAhvMT77_FvQ8XQ5hg8KdGk-d-/view?usp=sharing

but I don't know how pass data in listtile.

How can I make it possible?

```
 Wrap(
                      runSpacing: spacing,
                      spacing: spacing,
                      children: goodType
                          // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
                          .map((GoodTypes) => ChoiceChip(
                                label: Text(GoodTypes.label),
                                labelStyle:
                                    GoogleFonts.ubuntu(color: Colors.white),
                                onSelected: (isSelected) => setState(() {
                                  goodType = goodType.map((otherChip) {
                                    final newChip =
                                        otherChip.copy(isSelected: false);
                                    // print(goodType);
                                    return GoodTypes == newChip
                                        ? newChip.copy(
                                            isSelected: isSelected)
                                        : newChip;
                                  }).toList();
                                  print(GoodTypes.label);
                                }),
                                selected: GoodTypes.goodSelected,
                                selectedColor: AppColor.yellow,
                                backgroundColor: AppColor.blackrussain,
                                shape: StadiumBorder(
                                  side: BorderSide(color: AppColor.yellow),
                                ),
                              ))
                          .toList(),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you exactly want to do but you can pass data to another widget with the widget constructor method or pass arguments to a new screen like this:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
  context,
  ExtractArgumentsScreen.routeName,
  arguments: ScreenArguments(
    'Some data',
  ),
)
```

and get in second widget build method like this :

```
final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as ScreenArguments;
```

Comment: No I need to pass data to listtile